# How to save continuously data in one session_id in Firebase Realtime Database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to save the whole conversation of the user and the bot in the Firebase, but for me to easily retrieve the data, i need to save the whole conversation using the session_id of the user. how can i do this in Firebase? what i have right now is like this.

```
  function HandleSaveToDB(agent){

    return admin.database().ref('data').push({
        bot_response: request.body.queryResult.queryText,
        user_response: request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText,
        session: session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1]
    });
    
  }
```

so the output is look like this.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEq9q.png
```

What i want is the parent should be the session_id `session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1]`
and if the user interact again with the bot having the same session_id, it should not create another parent for that. it should be save continuously on the same session_id parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [`set()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#set) method instead of the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) one, as follows:

```
  function HandleSaveToDB(agent){

    return admin.database()
      .ref('data/' + session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1])
      .set({
        bot_response: request.body.queryResult.queryText,
        user_response: request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText
      });
    
  }
```

The `push()` method "generates a new child location using a unique key", while the `set()` one writes data to a specific database location (`'data/' + session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1]` in this case) and "overwrites any data at this location and all child locations".

---

**Update after your comment:**

If I correctly understand your comment, the following should do the trick:

```
  function HandleSaveToDB(agent){

    return admin.database()
      .ref('data/' + session_id_array[session_id_array.length - 1])
      .push({
        bot_response: request.body.queryResult.queryText,
        user_response: request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText
      });
    
  }
```

Comment: Hi sir @Renaud Tarnec thank you for the help, can i continuously insert data using the set? i tried to use it but it just overwrites the data the i have instead of inserting the data continuously that has the same session_id. i think the proper way to say this, is appending the data instead of overwrites it.